# How to find the points of self intersection of Cayley's Sextic?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am given that $Y(t)=\cos^3(t)(\cos(3t),\sin(3t))$ and need to find the unique point of self intersection. So I assumed $$\cos^3(t)(\cos(3t),\sin(3t))= \cos^3(u)(\cos(3u),\sin(3u)).$$ I took lengths and arrived at a solution of $u=\pi-t$. Then this implies that $t=n\pi/3$ for an integer $n$. I am not sure how $u=\pi-t$ implies that $t=n\pi/3$. Can I get an explanation, please?